# Made changes to folder structure locally, how to reflect these exactly in git/github?

Tags: git, github, directory

I had my git repo with files structured like this originally:

```
Folder
 - file1
 - file2
 - file3
 -....
 - file30
```

This was getting a bit hard to manage so I locally changed the structure to this:

```
Folder
 Subfolder
   - file1
   - file2
   - file3
   -....
   - file30
 
 Subfolder2
 ...
```

Basically inside my repo I did right click > new folder a few times and then dragged all my files into these new folders.

I then did:

```
git add *
git commit -m "foobar"
git push
```

However when I look on github I see my new folder structure fine, but all my old files are still in there as well, so it looks like I just copy and pasted my files into their new folders rather than moving them which is what I wanted.

```
Folder
 Subfolder
   - file1
   - file2
   - file3
   -....
   - file30
 
 Subfolder2
 ...

 - file1
 - file2
 - file3
 -....
 - file30
```

Below you can see my local file structure and my github repo that has all the extra "loose" files.

[image]

Can anyone help me remove these "loose" files from my github repo?

Comment: `git commit -a`

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

Git doesn't really files or track directories the way you think, and *adding* files to the index doesn't necessarily remove missing files, even assuming you actually moved or deleted the old ones. You can see what git thinks has changed in the index with `git status`.

In addition, the shell glob `*` only nets you the items in the current directory that don't match exclusions in your .gitignore file. Call `ls *` to see what the shell thinks you're adding to git's index.

### Solutions

If you've made significant changes throughout your directory tree, you can update the entire index rather than hand-crafting index changes. For example:

```
# change to your repo's top-level directory
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

# add the entire directory tree to the index
git add .

# update all blobs/trees that git is indexing
git commit -a
```

This should result in renamed, moved, and deleted files or directories that git was previously tracking being updated. With your current commands, you're only committing the top-level changes you're adding to the index with the shell glob `*`. This alternative approach will update your entire working tree while still respecting .gitignore.